# Quickinfo for Rectangle SVG Object/Raphael JS

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael, svg-animate

I am using Raphael JS for drawing Rectangle Objects. 
The JS Coding is converted by runtime to ABAP Coding and displayed in an internal Browser. 
While displaying everything is just fine, but I would like to post a spezific Qucikinfo when moving with the mouse over an SVG Object. Does anyone know how to post a quick Info by Rectangle Objects? An Info by klicking the Object would be also okay. I don't whant to use an circle object..

abap:

```
CONCATENATE: 'var' a_name '= paper.rect(' a_x_pos ',' a_y_pos ','
a_width ',' a_height ',' a_corner_radius ');'
INTO l_html_line SEPARATED BY space.
```

js:

```
var name = paper.rect( x_pos, y_pos, width, height, corner_radius)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check this out : http://stratha.us/raphael_js_tooltip

Code is very small:

```
Raphael.el.tooltip = function (tp) {
  this.tp = tp;
  this.tp.ox = 0;
  this.tp.oy = 0;
  this.tp.hide();
  this.hover(
    function(event) { 
      this.mousemove(function(event) { 
        this.tp.translate(event.clientX - 
          this.tp.ox,event.clientY - this.tp.oy);
        this.tp.ox = event.clientX;
        this.tp.oy = event.clientY;
      });
      this.tp.show().toFront();
    }, 
    function(event) {
      this.tp.hide();
      this.unmousemove();
    }
  );
  return this;
};
```

Then you just need to call

```
name.tooltip( paper.text( 0 , 0 , "Hi, I am a tooltip" ) );
```

On a side note, that ABAP code looks terribly hard to maintain. I would invite you to post the whole code on codereview.stackexchange.com, I am sure there is a better way to do this.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer! I posted my coding on codereview.stackexchange.com: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/26735/quickinfo-for-rectangle-svg-object-raphael-js